# Cannot save instanceState of activity containing fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains Tablayout and in each tabs i have two fragments that each contains recyclerview.

When I try to click an item in the recyclerview I want to transfer from another activity and save the instanceState of the source activity... However when I tried to accesss the Bundle it returns null.

This is my onClick() when the item was clicked for my tab named CasesResultsTab:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v, int position) {
    Case oCase = list.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewCaseActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", oCase.getCaseId());
    intent.putExtra("className", "SearchableActivity");

    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

So after that, i am saving the parent Activity's state like this:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putString("query", query);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

and onCreate I am accessing it like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        this.query = savedInstanceState.getString("query");
        Log.d("JC","Dito");
    } else {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            this.query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        }
    }

    Log.d("JC", this.query);

    setUpTabs();
}
```

When I tried to log the query it returns an error saying **java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message**
So technically, my Bundle is null at this point.

Why is that so?

Thanks!

Comment: Where or which code is it crashing? Either explain or post the logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

When you tested this, was the whole Bundle null or just the query field? Also, are you sure you've been testing the state restoration properly? In order to trigger onSaveInstanceState to be called, you have to either set "Don't keep Activities" to true in Settings and then background the app/bring it back to the foreground, or rotate the phone to do a view configuration change.